¿Cómo obtengo los datos del usuario logueado en Nextjs 15 y strapi?
Tengo un inicio de sesión usando como backend Strapi, lo que intento es obtener la informacion del usuario logueado en cualquier pagina, pero no puedo ya que al momento de verificar la cookie me manda este error:

"You're importing a component that needs "next/headers". That only
works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/
directory. Read more:

Tengo entendido que es porque intento usar next/headers en un "use client", pero entonces no se como obtenerlo.
// este es el form del inicio de sesion
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import { useActionState } from "react";

import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { loginUserAction } from "@/actions/auth-actions";
import { StrapiErrors } from "@/components/strapi-errors";
import { SubmitButton } from "@/components/submit-button";
import ZodErrors from "@/components/zod-errors";


const INITIAL_STATE = {
    zodErrors: null,
    strapiErrors: null,
    data: null,
    message: null,
};

const SigninForm = () => {
    const [formState, formAction] = useActionState(loginUserAction, INITIAL_STATE);
    return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-[70vh]">
            <div className="lg:p-8">
                <div className=" mx-auto flex w-full flex-col justify-
....


este es el loginUserAction que lo uso para validar datos y si todo esta bien guardo la cookie y lo redirijo a "/"
export async function loginUserAction(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
    const validatedFields = schemaLogin.safeParse({
        identifier: formData.get("identifier"),
        password: formData.get("password"),
    });

    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            zodErrors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
            message: "Missing Fields. Failed to Login.",
        };
    }

    const responseData = await loginUserService(validatedFields.data);

    if (!responseData) {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            strapiErrors: responseData.error,
            zodErrors: null,
            message: "Ops! Something went wrong. Please try again.",
        };
    }

    if (responseData.error) {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            strapiErrors: responseData.error,
            zodErrors: null,
            message: "Failed to Login.",
        };
    }


    const cookieStore = await cookies();
    cookieStore.set("jwt", responseData.jwt, config);

    //aqui se redirige a la pagina principal cuando se loguea correctamente
    redirect("/");
}


este es el auth-service que manda la peticion al backend de strapi y me devuelve la respuesta
export async function loginUserService(userData: LoginUserProps) {
    const url = new URL("/api/auth/local", baseUrl);

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...userData }),
        });
       
        
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Login Service Error:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

este es el auth-context y aqui es donde esta el problema ya que me pide el token de usuario y no se como obtenerlo
'use client';
import useUserStore from '@/hooks/use-current-user';
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchUser } from '../services/auth-service';


interface AuthContextProps {
  token: string | null;
  setToken: (token: string | null) => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | null>(null);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const setUser = useUserStore((state) => state.setUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    //obtener cookie llamada 
    const storedToken = ??????????
    if (storedToken) {
      setToken(storedToken);
      fetchUser(storedToken)
        .then((user) => setUser(user))
        .catch(() => {
         //remove token if user is not found
          setToken(null);
        });
    }
  }, [setUser]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

````
este es el que me da la cookie, pero me da el error
`````
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function getAuthToken() {
  const cookieStore = await cookies();
  const authToken = cookieStore.get("jwt")?.value;
  return authToken;
}

